# Filter text copied from PDF

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem while copying text from a pdf to MS SQL Server. This pdf contains a query, which I'd like to copy to my MS SQL Server but when I do this he copies the text including some invisible symbols.

Here the first part of the query, copied from my PDF viewer:

```
IF​O​BJECT_ID​(​'​trgAantalIU',​'​TR')​​I​S​N​OT​N​ULL
D​ROP​T​RIGGER​trgAantalIU;​ GO
CREATE​T​RIGGER​trgAantalIUO​N​bezettingsregel AFTER​U​PDATE
AS
BEGIN
```

When I view this copied query in SQL Server it doesn't get the correct syntax highlighting and I discovered that there is an invisible symbol between the 'B' and the 'E' (it requires two backspaces to delete the B while the cursor was in front of the 'E', is why I know this).

My question is: how can I delete those invisible symbols? I cant find an option in MS SQL Server to do this for me.

I'm using OS X 10.11, and the included 'preview' app as pdf-viewer. MS SQL is running in a VM (Parallels Desktop, latest version).

Comment: It's not a good idea to code an SQL query in pdf.

Pdf files are made for doing some other things.

Write the query in a plain txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to remove all the weird characters.
By far the easiest way to get rid of all these invisible characters is by using another application to paste text into without the actual formatting.

On Mac OS X you can use any text editor and paste the copied part into it with **Shift-Option-Cmd + v** to remove formatting.

If you are on windows you can copy/paste the code into notepad and it will lose all it's formatting (same thing works with [mousepad](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/mousepad), or [leafpad](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/)) under Linux.

For Windows there is also an application which you can use known as "[PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/)".

A short description about puretext:

> PureText only removes rich formatting from text.  This includes the font face, font style (bold, italics, etc.), font color, paragraph styles (left/right/center aligned), margins, character spacing, bullets, subscript, superscript, tables, charts, pictures, embedded objects, etc.  However, it does not modify the actual text.  It will not remove or fix new-lines, carriage returns, tabs, or other white-space.  It will not fix word-wrap or clean up your paragraphs.  If you copy the source code of a web page to the clipboard, it is not going to remove all the HTML tags.  If you copy text from an actual web page (not the source of the page), it will remove the formatting.

Comment: Thnx for the answer! I tried using my Mac Texteditor app, but i just pasted it with CMD+V and not with CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+V. Thnx, this worked for me!